# 总监，总统，总裁 and other similar words

Tags: difference, comparison

What's the difference between:
总
总监
总统
总裁
董事长
主任
领导
老板

They can all be translated as president,  chairman or boss.

I only know that 总统 is the president of a country, while 老板 is used in small firms and 领导 is a generic term for boss

Comment: answer in dictionaries, e.g.总监 inspector general ； chief inspector ；
    Director；Superintendent，Commissioner
一般为某项领域的第一监管人，如项目工程总监，财务总监，人力资源总监等，在企业中也是高层管理人员。

Comment: They can all be interpreted as: the one who can fire you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're really confused, and often changes meaning according to the context. Here're my opinions:

`总统` is the most clear one here, as you said, means `the president of a country`.

`董事长` means `chairman of the board`.

`总裁` (`president`), according to my experience, usually used for the CEO of a large company, which has a number of subsidiaries. BTW, `总经理` is often used for CEO too, but usually for a small or one-tier company.

`总监` is used for a chief officer of certain field, such as `技术总监` (CTO).

`主任`, and `主管`, means `director`, usually used for the people who are primarily responsible for an organization or department. Such as `财务主管` (`financial executive`), `教务主任` (`dean of students`).

`领导` is a generic salutation for your superior, immediate or non immediate.

`老板` (`boss`) is a generic salutation too, usually used for the top of your company, such as `总经理` (CEO).

Comment: 总经理 is GM. It refers to CEO for small companies only because CEO and GM is the same person.

Comment: I beleive 总监 is Director, 主管 is executive, 领导 is lead